# How to see error log file for php 7.4 in Magento 2 project (ubuntu)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

How to see error log file for **php** 7.4 in Magento 2 project which is working ubuntu. or how to set new log file location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following logs have a common location for all Magento projects:

```
Deployment log: var/log/cloud.log

Last deployment error log: var/log/cloud.error.log

Debug log: var/log/debug.log

Exception log: var/log/exception.log

System log: var/log/system.log

Support log: var/log/support_report.log

Reports: var/report/
```

Answer (score 1):

All errors (and other notices) are logged in files under `var/log` in the root of your Magento project. There you can find your error logs

Comment: But I'm not finding php error log file under magento 2 under var/log dir.

Comment: There are no php error log files in Magento. All the log files that exist in Magento are described by @divyarajsinh-barad in his answer.

Comment: And how about ubuntu log file for php errors?

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/14763/where-are-the-apache-and-php-log-files

Comment: I see it, but its for apache my engine is nginx

Comment: `sudo tail /var/log/nginx/error.log -n 200` will give you the last 200 logs. Change the number to get more or less.

Answer (score 0):

It is version dependent :

1. /var/log/nginx/error.log
   Or
2. /usr/local/var/log/nginx/*
   Or
3. /usr/local/nginx/logs/*

Comment: You can also check your nginx.conf

Answer (score 0):

You can also check your nginx.conf

```
"run nginx -t" command  to locate your nginx.conf.

In your ngingx.conf file :

    error_log  /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log;
    error_log  /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
    error_log  /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log  info;
```

here you can see the logs.